# Facing problem in "DOMContentLoaded" in jquery. without this jqgrid is loading , when adding this "DOMContentLoaded" not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Facing problem in "DOMContentLoaded" in jquery. without this jqgrid is loading , when adding this "DOMContentLoaded" not loading

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  $("#table").jqGrid({
    url: ROOT + 'PCM/DataToDisplayPCM',
    datatype: "JSON",
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    colModel: [{
      name: 'ProdPriority',
      label: 'Priority',
      index: 'ProdPriority',
      width: 50
    }, {
      name: 'ProductCode',
      label: 'Product Code',
      index: 'ProductCode',
      width: 80
    }, {
      name: 'ProductName',
      label: 'Product Name',
      index: 'ProductName',
      width: 200
    }, {
      name: 'DIV',
      label: 'Division',
      index: 'Division',
      width: 60
    }, {
      name: 'Category',
      label: 'Categary',
      index: 'Category',
      width: 150
    }, {
      name: 'SubCategory',
      label: 'SubCategary',
      index: 'SubCategory',
      width: 150
    }, {
      name: 'Priority_1',
      label: 'Priority_1',
      index: 'Priority_1',
      width: 80
    }, {
      name: 'Priority1per',
      label: 'Priority_1%',
      index: 'Priority1per',
      width: 80
    }, {
      name: 'Priority_2',
      label: 'Priority_2',
      index: 'Priority_2',
      width: 80
    }, {
      name: 'Priority2per',
      label: 'Priority_2%',
      index: 'Priority2per',
      width: 80
    }, {
      name: 'Priority_3',
      label: 'Priority_3',
      index: 'Priority_3',
      width: 80
    }, {
      name: 'Priority3per',
      label: 'Priority_3%',
      index: 'Priority3per',
      width: 80
    }, ],
    pager: "#prowed1",
    sortname: 'P_CODE',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc"
  });
  
  jQuery("#table").jqGrid('navGrid', "#prowed1", {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false
  });
});
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. Also, as you're using jQuery it would make more sense to use jQuery's document.ready handler instead of the native one: `jQuery($ => { $('#table').jQGrid....` etc

Comment: This could be because the loaded event already triggered. 
You could either replace the listener with $.ready(), or add a simple check of readyState and conditionally call the rest of the code. Something like this:
```
if (document.readyState != "loading") {
    // No need to listen for the event, just execute your code
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', yourFunction);
}
```